# How to translate allergy information

Tags: translation

I would like to translate the following for my trip to Italy.

> My son is allergic to all nuts (including for example walnuts, almonds
>   and hazelnuts) ,beans, pulses, peas, lentils and egg.

`Google Translate` offers this but I am not very confident about it.

> Mio figlio è allergico a tutti i dadi (tra cui ad esempio le noci,
>   mandorle e nocciole), fagioli, legumi, i piselli, lenticchie e
>   uova.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! The translation for *nuts* is *noci*; in this case it could be "frutti simili alla noce”; probably some expert in allergies has a better technical term.

Comment: And "dadi" it's indeed wrong; as Google Translate probably interpreted "nuts" as an acceptation of this: http://www.roolvit.com/image/cache/data/dado%20cieco-500x500.JPG. The other translations seem fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official European regulation can be found at http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/IT/TXT/?uri=celex:32011R1169

In the “Allegato II” we find the list of allergenic substances or products, which contains

> 8. Frutta a guscio, vale a dire:
>      mandorle (*Amigdalus communis L.*), nocciole (*Corylus avellana*), noci (*Juglans regia*), noci di acagiù (*Anacardium occidentale*), noci di pecan [*Carya illinoiensis* (Wangenh) K. Koch], noci del Brasile (*Bertholletia excelsa*), pistacchi (*Pistacia vera*), noci macadamia o noci del Queensland (*Macadamia ternifoliae*), e i loro prodotti, tranne per la frutta a guscio utilizzata per la fabbricazione di distillati alcolici, incluso l’alcol etilico di origine agricola.

So it seems that the technical term is *frutta a guscio*; the list should be known to all restaurant owners.

In the [English version](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32011R1169&from=IT), “Annex II” contains

> 8. Nuts, namely: almonds (*Amygdalus communis L.*), hazelnuts (*Corylus avellana*), walnuts (*Juglans regia*), cashews (*Anacardium occidentale*), pecan nuts (*Carya illinoinensis* (Wangenh.) K. Koch), Brazil nuts (*Bertholletia excelsa*), pistachio nuts (*Pistacia vera*), macadamia or Queensland nuts (*Macadamia ternifolia*), and products thereof, except for nuts used for making alcoholic distillates including ethyl alcohol of agricultural origin;

A translation that should be understood in restaurants and cafeterias might be

> Mio figlio è allergico a tutta la frutta a guscio (comprese, per esempio, noci, mandorle e nocciole), ai legumi (come fagioli, piselli e lenticchie) e alle uova.

Comment: Thank you very much! A version understandable in restaurants and cafeterias is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5):

My attempt, reorganizing *beans, peas, and lentils* under *pulses*, for clarity and safety:

> Mio figlio è allergico a tutta la **frutta secca a guscio** (ad esempio
>   noci, mandorle, nocciole, ecc.), a tutti i **legumi** (ad esempio fagioli,
>   piselli, lenticchie, ecc.) e alle **uova**.

As egreg points out, the technical term for *nuts* is *frutta a guscio* (literally: *shell fruits*), but what most people would say informally is *frutta secca* (literally: *dried fruits*). For the sake of safety I would leave the combination of both: *frutta secca a guscio*.

Comment: Thank you. Google seems to thinks `frutta secca a guscio` includes dried fruit. I wouldn't want to include that in the list.

Comment: @marsh "frutta secca" is a superset of "frutta a guscio"; hence "frutta secca" also addresses dried fruits without a shell, but "a guscio" narrows it down only to fruits with a shell, hence "frutta secca a guscio" is fine, unless there are dried fruits without a shell to which your son is allergic to (but then not even "frutta a guscio" would address those) or fruits not dried to which your son is allergic to (but then again, not even "frutta a guscio" would address those).

Comment: @marsh  However since this is something of a real concern, if I may suggest something, I would rather compile a comprehensive list of dangerous food, translate it and bring it with me, for the sake of avoiding any misunderstanding.